# Husky error in git prepush hook

Tags: git, npm, git-husky

I tried Husky as an easy git hook manager, and added the following line to my scripts in the `'package.json'` file:

```
"prepush": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js && git add ./dist_prod/* && git commit -m \"Automatic commit - webpack build prod\""
```

The problem is that everytime I try to do a `git push`, it fails, throwing this error:

> Cannot find module 'C:\c\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'

I understand the error is in this path, as "C:\c\" is obviously wrong, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: For future reference, upgrading to v1.0 fixed the problem